# Outlook 365: Unable to view calendar in meeting invitations

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've had an issue with Outlook for a while with the calendar preview in meeting invites seems to be compressed or squashed somehow, as shown in this image:

[image: Issue shown in this image]

I have reset my view and tested other views, to no avail. The issue persists regardless of if I'm in the viewing pane or if I open the invite. The issue persists regardless of whether I have responded to the invite or not. The following image shows the issue as it looks when opening the invite:

[image: Issue as seen when opening the invite]

There does not seem to be anywhere I can mouse-over to expand the calendar view.

I'm running Outlook 365 (v. 2108) on Windows 10, and have colleagues who have the same issue. I'm not really sure where to even start to troubleshoot this.

Update: When changing theme, the issue appears to disappear for the currently shown invitation. When switching to another invitation or email, however, the issue returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having posted this, I then started trying stuff out on my test machine (which also displayed the same behavior). As it turns out, this was readily resolved by reparing my Office installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad your problem has been solved. Allow my supplement, when you encounter some problems such as abnormal display in outlook, we can use the following two methods for simple troubleshooting：

1.Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in **safe mode**(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

2.If this is still the issue in safe mode, it is suggested that you could try to **create a new profile**(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

If the above is invalid, we can fix the office progarm or uninstall and reinstall.

Hope the above help!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: I cannot say one way or another whether the above was useful; the issue was resolved, and has not reoccurred.